# Rails Devise Password Recovery From: Address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, google-apps

Is there any way to change the "from:" address during password recovery to something other than what e-mail you use to login to the smtp server?

Here is how I set it up:

app/config/environments/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :port                 => 587,
 :domain               => 'domain.com',
 :user_name            => 'USERNAME@domain.com',
 :password             => 'PASSWORD',
 :authentication       => :plain,
 :enable_starttls_auto => true
 }
```

app/initializers/Devise.rb

```
config.mailer_sender = 'no-reply@domain.com'
```

When you get the password recovery e-mail, the "from:" address is USERNAME@domain.com and when you hit reply it's set to send to no-reply@domain. I'd like to change the "from:" address to no-reply@domain.com as well, or if possible maybe change it to one of the distribution groups I've set up in google apps (is there any way to authenticate using a group e-mail?). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately coming from Google's SMTP servers and has nothing to do with any Rails configuration. GMail will always default to use the account that you are signed in with as the from address.

There are ways to change it within GMail, but then all mail would default to sending from that address. Also, GMail does not allow authentication against a group.

Both this and Google's limit of 200 sent emails per day have forced me to seek alternatives. Currently I am using [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) for email in all of my apps. The configs are quite the same to that of GMail as far as your mailer smtp settings are concerned. Then you could override the from in the email that you want.